# Json parser 2 different types of attributs?

Tags: json, parsing, gson

I want to parse this JSON string using Gson

```
{"name":"name","type":["a","b","c"]}
```

is it possible?

1st attr String -> String;
2nd attr String -> Array< String >

Thanks for any helps.

edit:i mean 1 attribut return a string as "name" and 2nd attribut return a Array. Like in this example http://json.parser.online.fr/ Samples Johndo , they have parsed "ID" as "ID", "hobbies" as Array of "reading", "cinema".

But i want to do it as Javacode. Given a String like above, and parse an attr(a String) with an accordingly instance.

Comment: I only see one string, which is `name`. The other property is an array. What exactly is your problem?

Comment: i mean 1 attribut return a string as "name" and 2nd attribut return a Array<String>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following is an example of using Gson to bind the example JSON to a matching data structure.

```
import java.util.List;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class GsonFoo
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    String inputJson = "{\"name\":\"name\",\"type\":[\"a\",\"b\",\"c\"]}";
    MyThing myThing = new Gson().fromJson(inputJson, MyThing.class);
    System.out.println(new Gson().toJson(myThing));
  }
}

class MyThing
{
  String name;
  List<String> type;
}
```

Comment: To escape (preserve) the " character in the Java String literal.  The " is part of the JSON.